# LettuceConnectionFactory with SentinelTopologyProvider

Tags: redis, failover, sentinel, lettuce

I am using lettuce through the spring boot API `org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory` .

My bean is configured as

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceSentinelConnectionFactory() {
        RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration(mastername, new HashSet<>(sentinelnodes));
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
    }
```

This works fine, except for reconnecting after topology changes, resulting in exceptions.

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
```

Some bugreports seem to confirm this [behaviour](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/338/520274177) .

With great interest I read that lettuce implements a dynamic topology discoverer for sentinels [SentinelTopologyProvider](https://lettuce.io/core/5.0.1.RELEASE/reference/), which should fix the issue elegantly.

However I am unable to make the LettuceConnectionFactory use this dynamic SentinelTopologyProvider, and googling did not return anything neither.

Can anyone give a hint or some sample code on how to write this code?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: not really, I moved on to other problems.